# Ambiguity with str_replace case or replacement order

Tags: php, function, str-replace

Having strange problem with str_replace.

Here's my code:

```
function replace_text($text) {
        $array = array(
        ':big' => 'BIG',
        ':bigs' => 'BIIIGSS',
        );
```

The problem is when i enter `bigs` (with s) the code only turn the text to `BIGs` not `BIIIGSS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, bigs does match big as well, doesn't it? Change the order so it checks if bigs matches first:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $array = array(
    ':bigs' => 'BIIIGSS',
    ':big' => 'BIG',
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the case insensitive [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) instead.

What happens is by the time it gets to the second element in the array, the value is `BIGs`, so lowercase `bigs` is not present, and therefore not replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is your complete code, but just a function call to a function that calls `str_replace` multiple times?

If so, then you are probably first doing the first replace, so your string `bigs` is now `BIGs`. Then your second replace is run, but now you cannot find the lower-case string `bigs` anymore.

str_replace replaces from left to right by the way, as the manual says.